# WCF client timeout after 400 instance calls when not closing proxy

Tags: wcf

I am using the following code to investigate what happens when you fail to close the proxy:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 500; i++)
        {
            MakeTheCall(i);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("DONE");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void MakeTheCall(int i)
    {
        Console.Write("Call {0} - ", i);

        var proxy = new ServiceReference1.TestServiceClient();

        var result = proxy.LookUpCustomer("123456", new DateTime(1986, 1, 1));

        Console.WriteLine(result.Email);            

        //proxy.Close();
    }
}
```

The service is using net.Tcp binding,  WAS hosted, all default values.

Running it, I get a timeout when i > 400. Why 400 - is this a setting somwhere? I expected it to be much less - equal to maxConnections.

Answer (score 5):

By not closing the proxy, you are maintaining a session on the service. The maxConcurrentSessions throttling attribute controls how many sessions the service can accommodate. The default (in .NET 4.0) is 100 * Processor Count, so I am guessing that you have 4 processors (or cores) = 400 concurrent sessions?

Answer (score 0):

The reason your test code is timing out is probably due to the default WCF service throttling and doesn't have anything to do with not disposing of the proxy object. To conserve client-side resource, you should always properly dispose the proxy instance.

I believe that a service host will only create up to 16 instances of a service by default which may be even less if the binding is set to use session of some sort. You're flooding it with around 400 requests within a few seconds. There are a set of WCF [performance counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735098.aspx) you can fire up and view the instancing of a WCF service. I knew all that prep for the WCF certification exam would come in really useful sometime :)

Comment: Thanks, but if I uncomment the close proxy line then it completes all 500 iterations successfully, so I am not so sure that it is to do with service throttling. Thoughts?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I forgot about this answer. Service throttling could still come into play because of the different kinds of sessions that may be established in WCF. There are application (i.e. per session), transport, security, and reliable session types all of which count against the max sessions allowed setting. Closing the client could be completing the session termination process thus freeing up server side resources. The only "session-less" binding is basicHttp with no authentication configured. The other bindings use some sort of session to implement their capabilities.